# Python readlines not separating lines

Tags: python, io

I have a xml file from a page which shows correctly on the text editor but once I use readlines(), I only get one line. I assume this means the line separator being used isn't recognized by python but it is by gedit.

I want to do a split() on it to get the data correctly but how can I see what line separator is being used in the file?

Comment: Can you provide some code that shows what you have tried?

Comment: What is the point with reading XML files using readlines? The markup can have a line feed after tags or even inside the tag between attributes.

Comment: If data is xml why aren't you using an xml library e.g. ElementTree or other xml.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is pointed out in the comments, if it's xml, just hand it to an XML parser like ElementTree or lxml. Newlines shouldn't matter in XML.

For information, using `open("thefile.xml", "rU")` will open it with universal newline support, so Python will recognise `\n`, `\r` or `\r\n` as newline markers.

Comment: i was using lxml but the links i wanna extract from it are really simple, and i can just use string.find() instead. lxml was having problems because there are japanese (or other unsupported) characters in it so i decided to do it manually.

Comment: Never ever parse XML using string operations or regular expressions. That is absolutely worst-programming-style.

Comment: @gibem: If you know what character encoding was used to save it, you can use `codecs.open` to open the file, then read unicode from that and pass it to lxml.

Comment: string.find is never the correct thing with xml - lxml can deal with all valid xml including japanese characters much more reliable than you reinventing things

Comment: ah ok. i got it read with codecs.open and parsed it with lxml.html. thank you thomas.

Comment: @gibem: If it's xml, lxml.etree might be a better bet than lxml.html. But either is better than using string.find.

Comment: i use lxml.html these days because i had some problems with lxml.etree not reading malformed xml in the past iirc. i'll look into it later though. thanks again.